# get all username which are not there in other table comparing two tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to compare two database and get all users which are not there in other database. For eg database wp_members have the correct list of members and database members are missing some members then i want to compare wp_members and members usernames and find out which username in members are missing so that i can add them. (wp_members username should be selected)

Here is the SQL fiddle for the db

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a795e
```

And here is what i was trying to do

```
SELECT m.username FROM wp_members m, member n WHERE m.username<>n.username and n.siteid=1 group by m.username
```

But got no success.

Answer (score 0):

A general solution to this problem can be found by `LEFT JOIN`ing the tables and searching for `NULL` entries.

```
SELECT table1.id
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id=table1.id
WHERE table2.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot solve this problem with an inner join. Inner joins can only be done for rows that match the condition, not when there is 'no' match.

You can do a left outer join of both tables and match on username and then in the WHERE clause filter out the results that have a NULL value for n.username.

```
SELECT m.username FROM wp_members m LEFT OUTER JOIN members n ON m.username = n.username AND n.siteid = 1 WHERE n.username IS NULL GROUP BY m.username;
```

Another approach is to use a NOT IN statement with a subquery.

```
SELECT m.username FROM wp_members m WHERE m.username NOT IN (SELECT n.username FROM members n AND n.siteid = 1) GROUP BY m.username;
```

The solution with the outer join will be faster but maybe less trivial.

Comment: Where do i add check for site id which is in member table

Comment: Added it to the solutions.

Comment: Emm there are huge number of difference between data. Are we sure this is the correct way ?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure that my statements are 100% correct, I have no db and data available to test. But the idea behind it is correct.